# How to make Gradle copy source directories in certain order?

Tags: gradle

I need resources from "myOtherResourcesDir" to be copied to output directory before "src/test/resources".
It looks like FileCollection does not obey the order:

```
sourceSets.test.resources.srcDirs 'myOtherResourcesDir', 'src/test/resources'
```

UPDATE:
Can I configure processTestResources task to skip existing files?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up configuring processTestResources task with two "from". Files from 'src/test/resources' are copied last, so that they overwrite files from myOtherResourcesDir.

```
processTestResources {
    from 'myOtherResourcesDir'
    from 'src/test/resources'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate a bit what you're trying to achieve?

the files are copied in the `processTestResources`task. At the moment there is no way to specify the order when copying multiple directories

I assume the reason you need the ordering is, that a file in src/test/ressources overwrites a file copied from myOtherResourcesDir?. One option is to exclude that file specific file from 'myOtherResourcesDir' programmatically using the `eachFile` hook

```
processTestResources{
    eachFile{fileDetails ->
        if(fileDetails.file.absolutePath.contains("myOtherResourcesDir/fileToExclude.properties")){
            fileDetails.exclude()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: >>I assume the reason you need the ordering is, that a file in src/test/ressources overwrites a file copied from myOtherResourcesDir?<< Yes.